# App works fine in xcode in iphone/ipad, but crashes after iOS App File for Ad Hoc Deployment

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

My app works fine in iphone and ipad device but after make a iOS App File for Ad Hoc Deployment and use that build and install in ipad, it installed successfully but crashes in ipad on a view (that view contains collection view),
I check crash log in xcode window>devices> select ipad_device>view device log , I found this :

> Incident Identifier: BD46BB9B-369C-4D99-9BB2-F9756552B015
>   CrashReporter Key:   2e16bd23e21e8826a4e58f5d5b3be56b762922df
>   Date: 2015-05-21 16:18:52 +0530
>   Reset count: 0
>   Boot failure count: 1
>   Boot faults:
>   Boot stage: 255
>   Boot app: 1625695408

Comment: Check device iOS version ?

Comment: ipad version : 8.3 (12F69)

Comment: "I found this" Well, "that" is not a crash log. You need _information_ if you're going to track this down. You need an actual crash log.

Comment: @ManojGupta , do you got any solution on it?